# lapply for outliers poisition

Tags: r, outliers

I'm using this code to find the outliers in the data frame.

```
out<-lapply(df[,-1], function(x) boxplot.stats(x)$out)
```

The first columns are just the names (that's why I'm skipping it). I've found this method to detect the specific position of the outliers.

```
out_ind <- which(df$col1 %in% c(out))
```

But in my case, the object "out" is not a single *boxplot.stats(x)$out* so I cannot run the *which formula*.
How can I write it to find the outliers' position in every single data frame column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now have a list, so you need to iterate over it, e.g. using the `apply` functions:

```r
df  <- mtcars

out<-lapply(df[,-1], function(x) boxplot.stats(x)$out)

out_ind  <- sapply(names(df[,-1]), \(col) which(
    df[[col]] %in% out[[col]]
    )
)
# out_ind
# $cyl
# integer(0)

# $disp
# integer(0)

# $hp
# [1] 31

# $drat
# integer(0)

# $wt
# [1] 16 17

# $qsec
# [1] 9

# $vs
# integer(0)

# $am
# integer(0)

# $gear
# integer(0)

# $carb
# [1] 31
```

Comment: Your code does not work for me, it reports an error (even if I just try to use it on mtcars)

Comment: ... what is the error?

Comment: > out_ind  <- sapply(names(df[,-1]), \(col) which(
Error: unexpected input in "out_ind  <- sapply(names(df[,-1]), \"
>   out[[col]] %in% df[[col]]
Error in out[[col]] : invalid subscript type 'closure'
> )
Error: unexpected ')' in ")"
> )
Error: unexpected ')' in ")"

Comment: OK I see. I put the command on three lines to make it easier to understand what it's doing but it's one command - you need to run all three lines together rather than each line individually.

Comment: Still error..  Error: unexpected input in "out_ind  <- sapply(names(df[,-1]), \" 
I dont understand why since I am running your whole code

Comment: What version of R are you running? Just realised I am using the shortened `\(col)` for a function which will only work in 4.1 and above. If you replace `\(col)` with `function(col)` does it work?

Comment: Yes, changing "\" with "function" worked. I'll go for the update then! However I think that something is going wrong because it does not really tell me the position of the outliers, as the example you did with mtcars, that's not possible that the outliers are all in position 1.

Comment: Oh good point - I had it the wrong way round. It should be `df[[col]] %in% out[[col]]`. I have fixed it now.

Comment: Great! Now worked.